# How can I highlight the search terms with DB2 Text Search in 9.5.2?

Tags: sql, full-text-search, db2

I have a working search query with the new Text Search functions in DB2 9.5.2:

```
select * 
from prevue.mysearchabletable mst 
where contains(mst.searchabletext, 'porsche') = 1;
```

However, this only tells me which ones match, as well as what the score is (score function has been omitted for brevity).  Is there a way to use the text search in 9.5.2 to highlight search terms?

I know there were functions for this in the old Net Search Extender, but I haven't found equivalents (or a workaround) in the new text search system yet.